# FFMPEG x265.so.79 lib

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Trying to make some pictured from video with ffmpeg with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 01:23:45 -vframes 1 output.jpg
```

but constantly getting this error:

```
ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libx265.so.79: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

when i execute:

```
ldd $(which ffmpeg)
```

i get this output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff8417f000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f74c7130000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f74c6e27000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f74c6c09000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f74c6840000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000558ae35d3000)
```

After wasting multiple hours and trying to install modules and libraries to get through dependency hell still no progress, always getting that error.

Using Ubuntu 16.04.

I am desperate, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Show the **complete** console output from your command and also the output of `ldd $(which ffmpeg)`.

Comment: Added output to question